# Can't upload files to created disk in Laravel

Tags: laravel, upload, storage, disk

I have my public folder files in `/public_html/` and other files and folders in `/public_html/files`. Everything works fine except I can't link my storage directory via `php artisan storage:link` command because of my DirectAdmin host with limited functionalities. So I decided to create a new disk in public folder which is `/public_html/`. I added the following code to `config/filesystems.php`:

```
'uploads' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => public_path() . '/uploads',
],
```

Also used this code to upload files in controller but it upload file somewhere except the disk I defined.

```
$request->file('avatar')->store('avatars', 'uploads');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your new disk, you defined root folder as public_path which is public folder, not `storage/app/public` folder, your image saves in `public/uploads/avatars` directory if you want to move them to storage folder, Try:

```
'uploads' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public') . '/uploads',
],
```